# how to populate multiple dropdown depending on the select of another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

how to populate multiple dropdown depending on the select of another dropdown

i have this dropdown name section

```
<select name="section">
<option value="0">choose</option>
<option value="1">section1</option>
<option value="2">section2</option>
<option value="3">section3</option>
<option value="4">section4</option>
<option value="5">section5</option>
<option value="6">section6</option>
<option value="7">section7</option>
<option value="8">section8</option>
<option value="9">section9</option>
<option value="10">section10</option>
</select>
```

i have another 7 dropdown with names : subject1,subject2,subject3,subject4,subject5,subject6,subject7

i want to populate the 7 dropdowns with different values depending on the select of the dropdown "section"

for example when i select section1 from the dropdown "section" it populate

```
dropdown subject1 with "1"
dropdown subject2 with "2"
dropdown subject3 with "3"
dropdown subject4 with "4"
dropdown subject5 with "5"
dropdown subject6 with "6"
dropdown subject7 with "7"
```

and when i select section2 from the dropdown "section" it populate

```
dropdown subject1 with "a1"
dropdown subject2 with "a2"
dropdown subject3 with "a3"
dropdown subject4 with "a4"
dropdown subject5 with "a5"
dropdown subject6 with "a6"
dropdown subject7 with "a7"
```

and so on

Comment: you can use onchange event of first dropdown and according to its value you can write a javascript function to populate the data into second dropdown

Comment: By populate, do you mean to add items or select an item?

Comment: I want when i select section1 in section dropdown the other 7 dropdown subject1 to subject7 have a specific values

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<select name="section" onchange="yourfunction();">
....
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
yourfunction()
{
    // Your logic here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve you problem:

```
$('select').first().change(function () {    
$sub.hide();
if (this.selectedIndex > 0)
   $sub.eq(this.selectedIndex - 1).show();
}).change();
```

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CmYj/39/)**

Comment: this will populate another dropdown what if i want it to populate 3 dropdown

Comment: would be great if you can create a fiddle.

Comment: i still can not get you... :/

Comment: lets say the page have 4 dropdown first dropdown called section if i select section1 from it the other 3 dropdown get populated subject1 with value a - subject2 with value b - subject3 with value c

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42858/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-aloyoon)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar,  about this code, is there any way to remove the `Select` as the first option and automatically load the dropdown options depending on the first dropdown?